# Cosmic web shape

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, universe, structure-formation

Does anybody know why the cosmic web is shaped like a web? I feel like it would be more likely that it is more like a galaxy with a supermassive black hole in the center, if that were true, what would happen?

Comment: It's just a random distribution of the galaxies. It just looks like a web but you can see that it is not exactly webshaped as it is random. It might have been named Cosmic Web although it is not a web at all.

Comment: There are patterns to galaxies. This describes a subtle pattern caused by Baryon Acoustic Oscillations. [Sound Waves from the Beginning of Time](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PPpUxoeooZk)

Comment: Here is more on the structure. [Is it possible something in the universe is not orbiting anything?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/675888/37364)

Comment: The center of what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a neutral net:

[image]

It should be random on the largest scale, but there is clearly structure from dynamic interactions on large scales.

You really can't say what it would look if it looked like a giant galaxy other than, wait for it, a giant galaxy.

You'd have to get quantitive, include dark matter (ofc), and work out mass distributions for proper galactic rotation curves. It might not scale when the would-be galaxy size/time-scales require the Hubble constant be included into the dynamics.